# How to use substituted variables in appsettings.json in Azure pipelines?

Tags: .net, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, nunit, playwright

I have an NUnit test project for some Playwright tests where I'm testing a web page that requires login. Because it requires login I need to use some username and password. These tests are both meant to be run as part of a release pipeline, but should also be available through an endpoint so that they can be triggered as a CRON job. My entire solution looks like this:

[image: Solution]

With `appsettings.json` like this:

```
{
  "TestUser": {
    "Username": "",
    "Password": ""
  }
}
```

In the test class `AdminWebTests.cs` I set the username and password to be used in the tests through the constructor by injecting a `ConfigurationBuilder` and reading the `appsettings.json` file:

```
public class AdminWebTests : PageTest
{
    private readonly string _testUserName;
    private readonly string _testUserPassword;
    
    public AdminWebTests()
    {
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile(@"appsettings.json", false, false)
            .Build();

        _testUserName = configuration.GetSection("TestUser:Username").Value;
        _testUserPassword = configuration.GetSection("TestUser:Password").Value;
    }
}
```

This works perfectly locally, but I also need it to work in the pipeline. So in my pipeline script I have included the variable group which contains the variables to be substituted and a FileTransform task to replace the variables:

```
# ASP.NET
# Build and test ASP.NET projects.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/aspnet/build-aspnet-4

resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: playwright 
      source: some-other-pipeline 
      branch: master
      trigger:
        branches:
          - master

jobs:
  - job: Delay
    pool: Server
    steps:
      - task: Delay@1
        inputs:
          delayForMinutes: "1"

  - job: Build
    dependsOn: Delay
    condition: succeeded()

    pool:
      vmImage: "windows-latest"

    variables:
      solution: "packages/tests/playwright/*.sln"
      buildPlatform: "Any CPU"
      buildConfiguration: "Release"
      root_playwright: "packages/tests/playwright"
      group: playwright-ci

    steps:
      - task: UseDotNet@2
        displayName: "Set SDK version"
        inputs:
          packageType: "sdk"
          version: "6.0.x"
          includePreviewVersions: true

      - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
        displayName: "Install nuget"
        inputs:
          checkLatest: true

      - task: NuGetCommand@2
        displayName: "Restore"
        inputs:
          command: "restore"
          restoreSolution: $(solution)

      - task: FileTransform@1
        inputs:
          folderPath: "$(root_playwright)/Playwright"
          fileType: "json"
          targetFiles: "appsettings.json"

      - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
        displayName: "Build"
        inputs:
          command: "build"
          projects: $(solution)
          arguments: "--configuration $(buildconfiguration) --no-restore"

      - task: PowerShell@2
        displayName: Download Playwright Browsers
        inputs:
          targetType: inline
          script: |
            cd $(root_playwright)/Playwright
            dotnet build
            dotnet tool install --global Microsoft.Playwright.CLI
            playwright install

      - task: dotnetcorecli@2
        displayName: "Test"
        inputs:
          command: "test"
          projects: |
            $(root_playwright)/Playwright/*.csproj
          arguments: '--configuration $(buildconfiguration) --no-build --collect "code coverage"'
```

Now the problem is that the variables in the `appsettings.json` file don't seem to get replaced. In fact, the configuration doesn't seem to get read at all. Because if I try to print whatever value `_testUserName` and `_testUserPassword` get set to, they're blank. If I set them in the code and don't read them through the configuration, then the values get printed as the actual username and password so I know the logging/printing works fine. No matter what I put in the `appsettings.json` file in the code the variables turn out blank when running on the pipeline, but works fine locally. `appsettings.json` is copied to output directory, and the pipeline logs state that `JSON variable substitution applied successfully.` during the FileTransform step. Is there anything I have missed?

Update: I tried publishing the build artifact and saw that the variables `appsettings.json` file did in fact not get replaced, but remained as they were. I also tried putting the FileTransform stage after the build stage and running the transform on the outputted `appsettings.json` in the `bin/Release/net6.0` directory, but to no help.

Comment: I think that you are on good way. Could you display in logs content of the configuration file byt using `cat`? To be sure your replacement was correct. You could also publish `appsettings.json` as an artifact download it and verify.

Comment: Added an update to my post. Confirmed that the replacement does not work even though the log states that it does and prints the correct path to `appsettings.json`

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Replace Token** task from the market.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens

If you use $() for variables it would look more less like that:

```
- task: replacetokens@5
  inputs:
    targetFiles: '**/appsettings.json'
    encoding: 'auto'
    tokenPattern: 'azpipelines'
    writeBOM: false
    actionOnMissing: 'warn'
    keepToken: false
    actionOnNoFiles: 'continue'
    enableTransforms: false
    enableRecursion: false
    useLegacyPattern: false
    enableTelemetry: true
```

Comment: I guess. It just feels terrible to use a third party dependency when this is exactly what FileTransform is meant to do and that is implemented by Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that I simply used the incorrect syntax for the variable group name in the `variables` section of the pipeline script. Correct syntax is:

```
variables:
- group: playwright-ci
```

not

```
variables:
   group: playwright-ci
```

It's also important that the `group` variable is the first in the section.